# Cordova application hangs after a few minutes of usage (Android app)

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I have an Android Cordova/Angular JS application (not Ionic) that is running the latest version of Cordova (currently 7.0.1) - recently we have added a number of plugins related to using the Camera (see plugins below), the app itself is all working as intended however after 3-5 minutes of using the app it 'freezes' and becomes unusable.

Once it freezes the app seems to stay that way for a few minutes - the app itself doesn't actually crash/force quit but it seems to keep doing this and the user's only option is to close the app and re-open it to use it again.

I am testing this on a Galaxy Note 4 but it happens on my other devices also - Can anyone suggest what could be causing this, and what particular things should I be looking for within the adb logcat files?

So for the following seem to have popped up in the logcat - 

`W/PluginManager: THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Camera.takePicture blocked the main thread for 57ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool()
W/FileTransfer: setFixedLengthStreamingMode could cause OutOfMemoryException - switch to chunkedMode=true to avoid it if this is an issue.
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.212ms
D/CordovaActivity: Paused the activity.`

Any suggestions on how to start debugging this?

/ Plugins Installed /

`cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-filepath 1.0.2 "FilePath"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0 "Whitelist"`

Comment: This is the page you can get  all Debugging options on Android when you are using PhoneGap

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap

As there are quite few plugins are installed and i found Cordova's plugin architecture fragile.Use filters in Logcat for  errors and Try *Remote Debugging Tools for Chrome* or a tool like *Weinre*. These tools will show if there is a javascript error which blocks main thread or cause app to hang.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this plugin

> cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"

and use

```
cordova platform remove android 
cordova platform add android
cordova platform run android
```

Comment: tried this and still no joy, same as before will keep on it

Comment: Same here, removing compat didn’t work. The app freezes after roughly 10 clicks of navigation.